# Cross Domain Webservice Call

Tags: web-services, jquery, cross-domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-domain XHR/AJAX : a possible workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906903/cross-domain-xhr-ajax-a-possible-workaround)

I tried to do a `xmlHttpRequest` from within my Javascript to a Restful Web service which is running on an another server. I got an JS error specifying

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL'.Origin 'localhost' is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

After googling i got to know that i cannot make an `XmlhttpRequest` across domains.

I would like to know what is the best way to implement a cross domain web service call from my Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i am using this with my applications

```
function CrossDomainAjax(url, data, callback){
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonpCallback: callback
   });    
}
```

now for the server side function
it should return jsonp also, like this

```
callBack({your:json});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do changes on server to allow the request from your localhost server . You change settings in your apache’s  httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.com
DocumentRoot “C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/myApplication”
ServerName skill-guru.com
ErrorLog “logs/skg1-error.log”
CustomLog “logs/skg1-access.log” common


Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin “*”

<Directory “C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/myApplication”>
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

JkUnmount /*.jsp ajp13

</VirtualHost>
```

Now after you set the value in apache server and look at the header and would see

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 00:23:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.61
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
```

which essentially means your web service application’s server is serving request to any caller.

Comment: Is this possible in Apache Tomcat configuration, without using an Apache httpd?